# How to access react-list getVisibleRange() within a functional component

Tags: reactjs

react-list has a method "getVisibleRange()". getVisibleRange() => [firstIndex, lastIndex]. The examples show accessing this like so:

```
onScrollHandler() {
    console.log('onScrollHandler visible', this.getVisibleRange());
}
```

with the "this" keyword, within a class component. Is it possible to access the getVisibleRange() method within a functional component? For example:

```
const handleScroll = () => {
    let [firstIndex, lastIndex] = getVisibleRange() <-- ??
}
<div id="list" onScroll={handleScroll}></div>
```

UPDATE: reproducable code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactList from 'react-list'
var faker = require('faker')

const TalentSearch = () => {      
    let items = [...new Array(500)].map(() => faker.fake(faker.name.findName()))

    const renderItem = (index, key) => {
            return <div key={key}>{items[index]}</div>
        }

    const handleScroll = () => {
            // access getVisibleRange() here?
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Search Results</h1>
                <div id="list" style={{overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: 400}} onScroll={handleScroll}>
                    <ReactList
                        itemRenderer={renderItem}
                        length={items.length}
                        initialIndex={50}
                        type='uniform'
                        scrollTo={50}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default TalentSearch
```

Comment: Please make a reproducible example, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How your class is defined? Where `this.getVisibleRange` comes from

Comment: getVisibleRange() is a method in react-list: https://github.com/coderiety/react-list

Comment: I think its a method that you import, you can’t just use it, you must access it from some place

Comment: @DennisVash I've tried that. Unless I did it wrong. I've pretty much exhausted all of my noob knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access it through a reference, with hooks you may use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
const TalentSearch = () => {
  const listRef = useRef();
  return <ReactList ref={listRef} />;
};
```

Then you can access the methods like so:

```
listRef.current.getVisibleRange();
```